# Storing different objects as one object type (c++)

Tags: c++, class

I searched for this, but I feel I'm not finding the answer I'm after. So, simple version and hopefully someone can just say "here's how" and I'll be on my way :)

Essentially I want this:

```
class BaseObject
{
public:
    BaseObject();
    ~BaseObject();  
    virtual bool FunctionX() =0;
    virtual bool FunctionY() =0;
};

class ObjectA : BaseObject
{
public:
    ObjectA();
    ~ObjectA(); 
    bool FunctionX();
    bool FunctionY();
    bool FunctionZ();
};
```

.. same for ObjectB as above ..

...

```
vector<BaseObject*> myList;

ObjectA a;
ObjectB b;

myList.push_back((BaseObject*)&a);
myList.push_back((BaseObject*)&b);

myList.back()->FunctionX();
```

I know the code above is wrong, I'm just trying to get the overall concept over.

What I need:

A base class that defines functions that MUST be present in classes that inherit from it.

The ability to store the classes that inherit from it all in the same vector (cast as the base class).

The vector to know it can call the base classes defined functions.

The classes to be able to have their own, additional functions that the vector/base class do not need to be aware of.

Comment: you may want to look into an "abstract" base class, if you don't want the base to ever be a real object, but still have other classes inherit from it. A classic example of this is a "vehicle" class, that has functions like "move". You can never own a "vehicle" but you can own a "car", "plane", "boat", etc...

Comment: Why do you think the code is wrong? Aside from the limited life time of `a` and `b` (which need not be a problem), of course.

Comment: I don't see any obvious errors in what you've provided, other than that you need implementations for the member functions, and you should never use raw pointers. Use smart pointers unless you know why you need to use raw pointers. An expert will never use raw pointers if he can use smart pointers instead.

Comment: You probably want to write `class ObjectA : public BaseObject`.

Comment: @RobK: No C++ expert I know will *always* use smart pointers instead of raw pointers.

Comment: Thank you all for the responses. Is there a standard/often used library for smart pointers or is it a case of creating your own?

Answer (score 2):

I just noticed, you're deriving privately. BaseObject is a private base class of ObjectA. When you omit the inheritance specifier, you get private inheritance by default. Change the ObjectA declaration to

```
class ObjectA : public BaseObject...
```

Otherwise, code outside of the ObjectA scope is not allowed to know that ObjectA is-a BaseObject.

Comment: Missed this at first glance. +1

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost right. It misses the `virtual` for `BaseObject`'s destructor, however, which will invoke undefined behaviour (e.g. crashes) in any typical usage scenario. This is the correct declaration:

```
virtual ~BaseObject();
```

Another thing you should consider is making your public functions non-virtual and your virtual functions private, with the public functions delegating to the private ones (called [Non-Virtual Interface Idiom](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm) by Herb Sutter).

A few more things:

> A base class that defines functions that MUST be present in classes
>   that inherit from it.

You won't be able to achieve this, at least in the literal sense, by any normal means. A class can derive from your abstract class but *remain itself abstract* by not defining your pure virtual functions.

> The ability to store the classes that inherit from it all in the same
>   vector

Mind the difference between "class" and "object". A vector doesn't store classes but objects. In C++, classes cannot be used as objects (which is different in Java, for example). To "store classes" implies something like type lists in advanced template metaprogramming, a technique not related at all to your problem.

> (cast as the base class).

You do not need to cast from subclass to base class.